# getting different button height for the same button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a `Button` within `LinearLayout` and I want to retreive it's height.

I used `sample_button.getHeight()`, but it gives different valus of height.

i.e. I'm modifying height of the button based on `seekbar` progress as following :

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromTouch) {

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(50, progress * 20));

        lp2.setMargins(200, 0, 0, 0);
        sample_button.setLayoutParams(lp2);

Log.i("Activity", "progress = " + progress);
Log.i("Activity",
                "sample_button.getHeight() = " + sample_button.getHeight());
}
```

and the log values are as following:

```
progress = 1
sample_button.getHeight() = 60

progress = 2
sample_button.getHeight() = 20

progress = 3
sample_button.getHeight() = 40

progress = 2
sample_button.getHeight() = 60

progress = 3
sample_button.getHeight() = 40

progress = 4
sample_button.getHeight() = 60

progress = 3
sample_button.getHeight() = 80
```

Note that button is getting displayed properly but when `progress=2` , it shows `height=20` first but then it shows `height=60` and so on for other progress value as shown above.

Am I doing anything wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it this way:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = sample_button.getLayoutParams();
params.height = progress * 20;
sample_button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: but it's for setting the height of the button na? How does this help my cause? and where to put this code snippet?

Comment: I think that you are resetting your button, cause you aren't changing it's layout params, but passing new object. Hence the different heights.

Comment: You should try using it instead of lines: 4-8

Comment: I'm not able to crack where I'm going wring.